# Can I wget a file from an amazon instance without dns?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, wget

We have a lot of machines running ec2 instances, and one in particular which hosts Jenkins for various jobs. I need to get the Jenkins cli on another instance to do some development, but I cannot download the file to my new instance. Jenkins needs you to get the cli jar from your own Jenkins server so it needs to come from our network. Normally I should be able to use the dns name, but we are having problems with our dns and for the time being, I cannot use `our-url/file-i.want`.

I tried to get the private IP from the AWS console, but when I try and `wget` or `ping` the instance nothing happens. How can I access my instance when the dns is down? Do I have any options?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Jenkins isn't using name-based virtual hosts and that it's listening on all interfaces (e.g., bound to 0.0.0.0; by default `--httpListenAddress` listens on all), you should be able to. Your problem is likely with security groups.

If the two machines are connectable, you should be able to use `scp` also.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably not that "DNS is down". It's more likely that your security groups do not allow HTTP and ICMP ingress, or that you are trying to route requests to an unroutable address.

If you want a client EC2 instance to be able to retrieve files from your Jenkins server then you should probably allow SSH from client to server, install the appropriate private key on the client instance, and then simply use [scp](http://www.tecmint.com/scp-commands-examples/) to copy files from the Jenkins server.

An alternative would be to copy the files from the Jenkins server up to a private S3 bucket and then each client instance could retrieve the files from S3, assuming the client instances had the necessary S3 permissions.